# Разная длина ключа (key_len) в сложном запросе MySQL

Tags: mysql, opencart

При большом количестве товаров OpenCart умирает, перестаёт вообще отображать интерфейс. Выяснилось, что одним из самых медленных запросов (но частых) является

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total 
FROM oc_category_path cp 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= '2015-05-21 12:58:00' AND p2s.store_id = '0' AND cp.path_id = '823';
```

EXPLAIN по нему показывает разного размера индексы (key_len), хотя во всех таблицах идентификаторы типа int(11). Почему так происходит и как это лечить? Если мне не изменяет склероз, с точки зрения производительности такое расхождение плохо влияет

[image: Скрин профилирования]
<sub>(источник: [catalogloader.com](http://storage.catalogloader.com/screenshots/yar/2015-05-21_16-39-31_Ze2RVz9y.png))</sub>

Comment: А можно схему попросить с этими таблицами и этими колонками? Что-то, мне кажется, Вы не ту таблицу делаете в запросе главной (левой). Хотя, может быть, и ошибаюсь:трудно без схемы.

Comment: Ну, не я её делаю, это стандартная БД OpenCart. Более того вообще не понятно, зачем на титульной странице обходить ВСЕ категории поштучно, для каждой выполняя этот запрос (а длится он 2,5-5 секунд)